# Is it true that $A\cap (A\cap B)^{\perp} = A\cap B^{\perp}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\perp$ denote the orthogonal complement.

Is it true that $A\cap (A\cap B)^{\perp} = A\cap B^{\perp}$?

I know one containment easily follows as $A\cap B \subseteq B$. How about the equality?

Comment: You have an inclusion. What about dimensions?

Comment: Are they the same? I cannot see it easily.

Comment: Why not do an example with a tuple vs, where the inclusion is proper? That should give an idea whether it true or not.

Comment: $A=\{(x,0): x \in \mathbb R\}$, $B=\{(x,x):x \in \mathbb R\}$.

Comment: @ThomasPreu if you are mentioning the proper inclusion $A\cap B \subset B$, I already tried some examples and still I did not find a counter example

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't follow your final remark that one containment follows easily.  Note that $(A\cap B)^\perp$ is not the same as $A\cap B^\perp$.  But it is a good tactic to sort out whether one direction of containment is easier than the other.

Comment: I’d be inclined to accept as *context* a clearer statement about which containment is easy.  In its present form that final remark of the Question body seems to be a misreading, but I'd happily vote to reopen if it can be clarified.

Answer (score 1):

The question is equivalent to: Does $x\in A$ and $x$ orthogonal to $A\cap B$ already imply $x$ orthogonal to $B$?

Suppose $y$ in $B$ so that $x$ is not orthogonal to $y$. This can only be the case if $y\in B\setminus A$. Suppose $V=R^3$, $A=[e_1+e_2]$, $B=[e_1,e_3]$. Now clearly $A\cap B = \{0\}$. So $A\cap(A\cap B)^\perp = A$. But $B^\perp = [e_2]$, so $A\cap B^\perp = \{0\}$.

Comment: @hardmath The intention is to not simply provide a counterexample but to provide a context of how this counterexample is constructed. For a counterexample we need at least one $y\in B\setdiff A$ that is not orthogonal to $A$.